# Casperjs 1.1 does not generate XUnit xml file

Tags: javascript, xml, casperjs, xunit

I am running CasperJS tests. I tried to generate xUnit xml file in output rendering. But this fails when ever a single FAILure occurs. Actually the executing stopped when a single FAIL occurs.

Here is the script that I am working on

```js
casper.test.begin('Site login', '', function suite(test) {
   casper.start(mysite, function () {    
      test.assertExists('form#index', "Login Form found"); //Pass
      test.assertExists('form#index1', "Login Form found"); //Fail
   });

   casper.run(function (){
      test.done();
      test.renderResults(true, 0, 'test1.xml');
   });
});
```

Comment: Question asked in March 2013. 3 years later, no answers and CasperJS is still in 1.1 beta with same bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`casperjs test`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html) with the `--xunit=<filename>` option.

Comment: This does not work when I run casperjs test against a folder of test files, more details here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467310/xunit-output-when-running-a-directory-of-tests -- Would you know how this could be achieved?