# --xunit output when running a directory of tests

Tags: testing, casperjs, ui-automation

There is a similar question here - [Casperjs 1.1 does not generate XUnit xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363182/casperjs-1-1-does-not-generate-xunit-xml-file)

The answer to linked question works when one is executing single .js files, when I trigger the script with casperjs test /path/to/test/files, then multiple test suite files in the folder get executed in sequence, and when that happens the file name in --xunit parameter doesnt get written to. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with CasperJS 1.1-beta3+PhantomJS 1.9.7 or CasperJS current master+PhantomJS 2.0.1. Perhaps you forgot to specify the filename? `--xunit=<filename>`

Comment: @ArtjomB. This is the command I am using 
casperjs test --xunit=/home/vatsala/sample_folder/test_output.xml casper_tests/sample_test/test.js

Comment: @ArtjomB. When I run above command as 
casperjs test --xunit=/home/vatsala/sample_folder/test_output.xml casper_tests/sample_test/  
I dont see the output getting written to the given file. The example folder name specified here has >1 .js files containing tests

Comment: Same problem, no paths or multiple scripts involved. Have 1 script (Test.js) that runs multiple tests. No output file from --xunit. Command: `casperjs --log-level=debug --xunit=log.xml test Test.js`